# Practica con For e if/else en Python

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles

Bueno se supone q mi programa debe recibir un numero q indicará el numero de veces q el ciclo for hara su trabajo, luego pedira un numero, luego pedira otro numero(q deberia ser mayor que el primero); mediante if/else debe reconocer si el primer numero es menor o mayor que el segundo. Si el numero es menor debe imprimir un texto donde lo anuncia, de lo contrario imprime un texto agradeciendo la cooperacion.
El problema es q escribo un numero cualquiera y de algun modo hace lo contrario. Si ingreso 2 en el primer numero y luego 100 en el segundo, el if/else me dice q el segundo numero introducido es menor q el primero wtf!

```
n=int(input("Cuantos numeros se van a introducir?: "))

for i in range(0,n):
  numero = float(input("Ingrese un numero: ")) 
  numero2 = float(input("Ingrese un numero mayor: ")) 
  if numero < numero2:
        print("El numero es menor!")
  else:
        print("Gracias por su cooperacion.")
```

Esto sale en consola:

```
Cuantos numeros se van a introducir?: 2
Ingrese un numero: 2
Ingrese un numero mayor: 5
El numero es menor!
Ingrese un numero: 4
Ingrese un numero mayor: 1000
El numero es menor!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya he revisado el código y tenías las variables al revés:

```
n=int(input("Cuantos numeros se van a introducir?: "))

for i in range(0,n):
  numero1 = float(input("Ingrese un numero: ")) 
  numero2 = float(input("Ingrese un numero mayor: ")) 
  if numero2 < numero1:
        //como el numero2 es menor que le numero1 imprimimos lo siguiente
        print("El numero es menor!")
  else:
        print("Gracias por su cooperacion.")
```

Answer (score 1):

El código funciona correctamente: ingresa dos valores (`numero` y `numero2`), donde se supone que el primero es menor que el segundo, de acuerdo con la comparación:

```
if numero < numero2:
```

Si pruebas con valores 2 (`numero`) y 5 (`numero2`)

```
Cuantos numeros se van a introducir?: 2
Ingrese un numero: 2
Ingrese un numero mayor: 5
El numero es menor!
```

el código correctamente dice que `numero` es menor que `numero2`.

Si por el contrario, ingresas 5 y 2

```
Cuantos numeros se van a introducir?: 2
Ingrese un numero: 5
Ingrese un numero mayor: 2
Gracias por su cooperacion.
```

correctamente detecta que `numero` ya no es menor que `numero2`.